# Jquery-Hot key responds to every key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have downloaded jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.js plugin and was trying to provide hot key. on pressing  ctr+t it should open new url address . i have made this something like this

```
 jQuery(document).bind('keypress', 'Ctrl+t',function (evt){ 
  alert('ctrl+t is pressed');
  window.location.href = ("${createLink(controller:'trip',action:'create')}");
   return false
 });
```

But this is not working, it resonds to any key in my keyboard,(even if i press a,b,c etc). What changes i should make so that it should respond to only ctr+t  ??
even if i delete the downloaded plugin from js folder the result is same\

jquery version i am using is  **jquery-1.1.3.1.pack.js**

Comment: What browser are you using ? Is there any errors that you see on the console ? There should be a `;` after `return false`

Comment: there is ; after return false , there is no error message , on pressing any key it redirects to specified url in window.location.href i am using mozilla browser (current version)

Comment: If a website overrides the default <ctrl>+t behaviour (opening a new tab), I would personally try to find out the address of the creator of this website and pay him/her a visit, and punch this person to the face ->   ,('^')=@

Comment: No it is not opening the new tab, it redirects to specified url , but it binds any key

Comment: @Hussain - @Justus is saying ctrl-t has a purpose and you are breaking it.

Comment: Why in the world are you using a version of jquery that is 4 years old?

Comment: i changed it to ctrl+v then also it responds to every key....

Answer (score 3):

According to the example the project gave, you should do this:

```
$.hotkeys.add('Ctrl+t', function(){
    alert("haha");
});
```

But in Chrome(and maybe some other browsers too), Ctrl+t is the default hot key to open a new tab, I don't know how to overwrite it. So when I test, I replace `Ctrl+t` to `Ctrl+v`, and it worked.
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QFT8f/
UPDATE:
This is copied from the source file of [hotkey.js](http://js-hotkeys.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.hotkeys.js):

```
USAGE:
    $.hotkeys.add('Ctrl+c', function(){ alert('copy anyone?');});
    $.hotkeys.add('Ctrl+c', {target:'div#editor', type:'keyup', propagate: true},function(){ alert('copy anyone?');});>
    $.hotkeys.remove('Ctrl+c'); 
    $.hotkeys.remove('Ctrl+c', {target:'div#editor', type:'keypress'});
```

Comment: what this mean ?? so many confusion.. it gives error  $.hotkeys is undefined

Comment: @Hussain did you see my jsfiddle? It worked fine with JQuery 1.6 and http://js-hotkeys.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.hotkeys.js

Comment: I tried your link there also i am getting error message saying  $.hotkeys is undefined

Comment: @Hussain you can see usage example in the script.

Comment: @Hussain I updated the answer, check it. And try to use a newer version of JQuery

Comment: jquery-1.1.3.1.pack.js is 4 years old! It does not equal 1.6 :)

Comment: is it the problem with jquery version 1.1.3.1 ?:))

Comment: @Hussain I seems the plugin should be used with JQuery 1.2+, give it a try, anyway, you really should update your JQuery..

Comment: @Hussain glad to be helpful. :)

Comment: just replacing jquery 1..13.1. with 1.6 version will work right ??

Comment: jQuery(document).bind('keypress', '',function (evt){alert('pressed')} not that i haven't mentioned any key still it binds every key and display "pressed" what's wrong? can u think of anything??

Comment: @Hussain don't use bind, it seems that the usage has been changed. use the format I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Hussain Which version of Firefox are you using? worked fine for me on Firefox4. Just visit the fiddle I paste in the answer!

Comment: i am using latest version of firefox(5.0)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct based on the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/wiki/about), but the plugin does not work as expected (at least in Firefox).  I would ditch the plugin and just handle it based on event attributes.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/K22hu/)'s a fiddle with the plugin installed where you can see the event firing when any key is pressed, and how you would limit to only run certain code when 'Ctrl+t' is pressed.  Note: you have to click on the output panel to give it focus for the key events to fire.

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', 'Ctrl+t',function (e){
    if(e.which==116 && e.ctrlKey){
        alert('Ctrl+t was pressed');
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Any other key.  Bad code...BAD!');
    }
    return true;//Pass the event on
});
```

**UPDATE**

I had previously added the plugin when I was testing, but it appears like I lost it somewhere when I was fiddling, so the example above works in plain JQuery (I'd make the second parameter the function though).  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/K22hu/3/)'s the fiddle with the **jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.min.js** resource added with the same code, and for me it throws an `"elem.getAttribute is not a function"` JavaScript error when run with JQuery 1.6.  Another reason to ditch the plugin!